# Angular 4.3 HttpClient Interceptor

Tags: angular

Please advise why the route redirection is not working when response is 401. Console.log shows the response object and status as 401 but router is not redirecting user to logout page.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

            this.onStart();
            return next.handle(req).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) =>
                (error: any) => {
                    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                        if (error.status == 0 || error.status == 401 || error.status == 404 || error.status == 500 || error.status == 503) {
                            this.storageService.writeToStorage(Constants.STORAGE_KEY_ERROR, error);
                            console.log(error);
                            this.router.navigateByUrl(Constants.ROUTE_ERROR_DYNAMIC + error.status);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        return Observable.throw(error);
                    }

                }).finally(() =>{
                    this.onEnd();
                })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable()
export class AngularInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private router : Router){}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).do(event => {}, err => {
        if(err instanceof HttpErrorResponse){
            console.log("Error Caught By Interceptor");
            //Observable.throw(err);
            this.router.navigate(['a4']);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Revised code working. Change the code to use catch block.

```
 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        this.onStart();
        return next.handle(req)
            .catch((error: any) => {
                if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                    if (error.status == 0 || error.status == 401 || error.status == 404 || error.status == 500 || error.status == 503) {
                        this.storageService.writeToStorage(Constants.STORAGE_KEY_ERROR, error);
                        this.router.navigateByUrl(Constants.ROUTE_ERROR_DYNAMIC + error.status);
                    }
                }
                return Observable.throw(error);
            })
            .finally(() => {
                this.onEnd();
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

adding `return Observable.empty();` helped in my case

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    this.onStart();
    return next.handle(req)
        .catch((error: any) => {
            if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                if (error.status == 0 || error.status == 401 || error.status == 404 || error.status == 500 || error.status == 503) {
                    this.storageService.writeToStorage(Constants.STORAGE_KEY_ERROR, error);
                    this.router.navigateByUrl(Constants.ROUTE_ERROR_DYNAMIC + error.status);
                    return Observable.empty();
                }
            }
            return Observable.throw(error);
        })
        .finally(() => {
            this.onEnd();
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a hell of a time with this.

In my case, I request for an API, but when I got 401 message.
I would go to the login page.

But The Router didn't work.

What I finally found was that the existing request had to be finalized.

The way is to receive the error message and process it by requester.

just call **"resolve(err)"**

Because You should let them go first. you route your navigation url before your latest request call.

Otherwise, existing requests remain.

The flow..

1) request the http call.

2) received response 401 error in interceptor.

3) route your path

4) **throw error**

5) received error in error area.

6) **resolve(err) or other message**

In service.

```
getUserInfos(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get('/api/userinfo/list')
          .subscribe((response: any) => {
            this.userInfos = response.data;

            if (this.searchText && this.searchText !== '') {
              this.userInfos = FuseUtils.filterArrayByString(this.userInfos, this.searchText);
            }

            this.userInfos = this.userInfos.map(userInfo => {
              return new UserInfo(userInfo);
            });

            this.onUserInfosChanged.next(this.userInfos);
            resolve(this.userInfos);
          }, **err => {
            resolve(err);
          }**);
      }
    );
  }
```

.Interceptor

```
import {
  HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest,
  HttpResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import {FuseConfigService} from './config.service';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private router: Router, private fuseConfig: FuseConfigService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log('INTERCEPT REQUEST: ', req);
    return next.handle(req)
      .map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse && ~(event.status / 100) > 3) {
          console.log('INTERCEPT RESPONSE[' + event.status + ']: ', event);
        } else {
          console.log('INTERCEPT RESPONSE[' + event.type + ']: ', event);
          if(event['body'] && event['body'].code == -444) {
            this.router.navigate(['pages/auth/login']);
          }
        }
        return event;
      })
      .catch(
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log('INTERCEPT ERR[' + err.status + ']: ', err.statusText + ' / ' + err.url);
        if(err.status === 401) {
          this.fuseConfig.setSettings({
            layout: {
              navigation: 'none',
              toolbar   : 'none',
              footer    : 'none'
            }
          });
          **this.router.navigate(['pages/auth/login']);
          return Observable.throw('Unauthorized');**
        }
        return Observable.throw(err);
    });
  }
}
```